# Keeping bold, color, and italics when copying text between two text areas in my HTML/CSS/JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code in which I remove the extra spaces and with a few more changes... I have two text areas, in the first one I put the text without formatting and another where the already formatted text will arrive. I'm having trouble retaining text edit settings (eg bold, color, italics, etc.). For example, if I put a text already with bold, color, and italics in area1, I want it to modify the text keeping these settings. Below is the code:

```js
var resultado = [];

function Remover() {
  debugger
  var text1 = document.getElementById("areaText1");
  var text2 = document.getElementById("areaText2");
  var palavras = [];

  var textoFormatado = text1.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  text2.innerHTML = textoFormatado;
  lerTexto(text1.textContent);
  // palavras = text1.textContent.split(/\s+/g);

  // text2.textContent = palavras.join(' ');
}

function Aplicar() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("areaText2");
  var colorPicker = document.getElementById("cor");

  if (document.queryCommandSupported('styleWithCSS')) {
    document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
  }

  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, colorPicker.value);
}

function Formatar(command) {
  document.execCommand(command, false, null);
}

function lerTexto(texto) {
  debugger
  var linhas = texto.split('\n');
  var textoFormatado = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
    var linha = linhas[i];
    var novaLinha = '';

    for (var j = 0; j < linha.length; j++) {
      var letra = linha[j];

      if (letra == ';') {
        novaLinha += letra + "<br><br>";
      } else if (letra == '.') {
        novaLinha += letra + "<br><br>";
      } else {
        novaLinha += letra;
      }
    }

    textoFormatado += novaLinha + '\n';

  }
  var textArea2 = document.getElementById("areaText2");
  console.log(texto);
  console.log(textoFormatado);
  textArea2.innerHTML = textoFormatado;

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Asap';
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: rgb(130, 203, 227);
}

#fundo {
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  width: 1100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(96, 183, 212);
  background-color: rgb(148, 212, 234);
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.areaText {
  display: block;
  min-width: 460px;
  max-width: 500px;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: .8em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  user-select: all;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#btnFormatar {
  background-color: #2a90b0;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  /* margin-left: 5px; */
  position: relative;
  left: 77%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* transform: translateX(-42%); */
}

section>#spanEdit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 58.5%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  display: block;
}

#spanColor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  display: block;
}

.btnsEdit {
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #2a90b0;
  color: white;
}

.btnsEdit:hover,
#btnFormatar:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 0px #186378ce;
  background-color: #3b9bb8;
  transform: translate(-1px, 1px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Remove espaços</h1>
  <div id="fundo">
    <section>
      <label for="areaText1">Texto</label><br>
      <div placeholder="Coloque o texto que deseja formatar aqui" id="areaText1" class="areaText" cols="60" rows="10" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="resize: none;"></div>
      <input type="button" onclick="Remover()" id="btnFormatar" value="Formatar">
    </section>
    <section style="float: right;">
      <label for="areaText2">Formatado</label><br>
      <div placeholder="Texto formatado" id="areaText2" class="areaText" cols="60" rows="10" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="resize: none;"></div>
      <span id="spanEdit">
                <!-- italico -->
                <input type="button" class="btnsEdit" value="Itálico" onclick="Formatar('italic')">
                <!-- negrito -->
                <input type="button" class="btnsEdit" value="Negrito" onclick="Formatar('bold')">
                <!-- underline -->
                <input type="button" class="btnsEdit" value="Linha" onclick="Formatar('underline')">
                <!-- cor -->
            </span>
      <span id="spanColor">
                <input type="color" class="btnsEdit" id="cor">
                <input type="button" class="btnsEdit" value="Aplicar" onclick="Aplicar()">
            </span>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!-- Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi nobis ipsa magnam nulla quidem? Temporibus, nulla. Mollitia natus, sit aperiam aspernatur sunt iure. Numquam quaerat quasi mollitia iure sapiente commodi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A dolores mollitia cum fugiat id eius, dicta recusandae iusto. Error, hic aspernatur. Velit, cum dicta. Numquam vitae hic impedit modi perspiciatis. -->
```